# PyTorch: How to convert SentencePiece numbers into tokens

Tags: pytorch, torchtext

PyTorch's torchtext can convert tokens into integers via [`sentencepiece-numericalizer`](https://pytorch.org/text/stable/data_functional.html#sentencepiece-numericalizer).  E.g. `"is" -> 17"`.

What about the inverse operation, from integer to a token? E.g. `17 --> "is"`.  How can I do that? It's not listed in the https://pytorch.org/text/stable/data_functional.html API doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the code for the sentencepiece_numericalizer in PyTorch, it looks like this (docs removed):

```py
def sentencepiece_numericalizer(sp_model):
    def _internal_func(txt_iter):
        for line in txt_iter:
            yield sp_model.EncodeAsIds(line)

    return _internal_func
```

Note the call to `sp_model.EncodeAsIds(line)`.

Based on this, it appears that the sp_model argument (the same returned by `load_sp_model`) is actually an instance of the [SentencePieceProcessor](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece/blob/f2219b53e24ff5deee4cacdc2d0ca3074e529a07/python/src/sentencepiece/__init__.py#LL241C21-L241C21) class. Looking through the code, there is an additional `DecodeIds` method.

With the above information we can write the inverse function to `sentencepiece_numericalizer`

```py
def sentencepiece_denumericalizer(sp_model):
    def _internal_func(id_iter):
        for ids in id_iter:
            yield sp_model.DecodeIds(ids)

    return _internal_func
```

This can be used like below:

```py
from torchtext.data.functional import (
    load_sp_model,
    sentencepiece_numericalizer,
)
sp_model = load_sp_model("path_to_model")
sp_nm = sentencepiece_numericalizer(sp_model)
sp_dnm = sentencepiece_denumericalizer(sp_model)

in_strs = ["sentencepiece encode as pieces", "examples to   try!"]
ids = list(sp_nm(in_strs))
out_strs = list(sp_dnm(ids)) # should approx eq. in_strs
```